# Sharing internet between Mac mini (with Ubuntu) and Android

Tags: wireless, networking, android, mac

I have an old Mac mini on which I installed Ubuntu. It works quite fine except for few issues.

One of the issues is as follows: I used this Mac Mini as a hot-spot for sharing ethernet -> wi-fi connection. I have the Mac connected to standard ethernet, I used to start a hotspot and I have Android tablet, phone and kindle connect to that (and therefore to the internet).

However, since I switched to Ubuntu, it doesn't work.

My ethernet connection 100% works. My Wi-fi 100% works as on itself in both ubuntu and OS X. Sharing connection works in OS X, but not in Ubuntu.

When I go to the Network settings, select Wireless, select "Use as Hotspot", it generates a random WEP password (without any possibility to change it or turn it off, but OK), I see the WiFi on my tablets, but if I want to connect to the WiFi, it gets stuck on "getting IP address" on the Android. So Android sees the network, but can't connect to it. The same with non-Android WiFi enabled toys.

What should I do? I just want to share the connection to all my WiFi enabled toys. And it works great if I reboot to OS X.

I don't understand ifconfig and routing tables that much, so I am little afraid of that, but if it's needed I will go there and edit something/run some scripts. I don't care, I just want to share the damned connection.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, nevermind.

The problem was that I didn't select "Share with other computers" at the wired connection settings.

(see: http://narnicles.wordpress.com/2011/06/17/sharing-your-internet-connection-in-ubuntu-through-wifi-and-ethernet/ )